# Change the way annotate() places text in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am annotating a plot made with `ggplot` with `annotate()` as follows:

```
annotate("text", x = 1, y = 2,label = "TEXT")
```

When I have multiple annotations with different lengths it is difficult to keep them left-aligned for example, as the x and y coordinates refer to the middle of the string. Is there a way to have the x and y coordinates refer to the left-hand side of the string?

Comment: Do you mean `hjust = 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to teunbrand :

```
annotate("text", x = 1, y = 2, hjust = 0 ,label = "TEXT")
```

Comment: Please feel free to accept your own answer if it solved the problem

Comment: Yes I tried, but it won't let me until two days have passed. Thank you for your suggestion above.